# Edge-Chromium GP - How to set google as default, bypass first run dialog, and have tab page without news?

Tags: registry, microsoft-edge, chromium, group-policy

#### Problem With Default Search Provider

---

Reading the Microsoft Group Policy docs, I've set these policies:

- Microsoft Edge->Default Search Provider->

  - Default search provider name

  ```
  Google
  ```

  - Default search provider search URL

  ```
  '{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}'
  ```

This does not seem to work, Bing is still the default. **Could someone assist/provide gp settings that will work?**

#### How to Disable First Run Page?

---

I cannot find a Group Policy to disable the white splash Edge Chromium welcome page on first run.  I've read about registry edits under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge]
HideFirstRunExperience=1, but would like to keep it under Group Policy if possible rather than setting a registry change.

**Is there no official group policy to disable the first run experience?**

#### How to Disable the scrollable Tab page?

---

I would like to keep the tab page in edge chromium, but only the tabs, not the scrollable Microsoft news section that's there by default.

**Is there a group policy to remove the news section?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Edge version 81.0.416.64, I've been able to now get these to work:

## Default Search Provider

- User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge > Default Search Provider >

```
Enable the default search provider: Enabled
Default search provider name: Google
Default search provider url: {google:baseURL}search?q={searchTerms}&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}ie={inputEncoding}
Default search provider URL for suggestions: {google:baseURL}complete/search?output=chrome&q={searchTerms}
```

## Disable First Run

- Policy exists in the latest ADMX templates as outlined by Deepak-MSFT in his answer.

Disabling the scrollable tab page does not seem possible through group policy.  It can be changed by manually editing the users configuration file, but it's more of a hassle than it's worth at this time.

Answer (score 3):

for anyone who has come to this page via google search:
in the search provider URL setting, like this:

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}
```

There are many conflicting formats found from search. The above is a working format for using the Edge group policy.
**Note**, many answers around the web do not include the "%s&" after "search?q". **You need that %s&**

Here is the registry settings I use for workstations. I manually set the options via local group policy on a workstation, then exported the associated (computer wide) registry key.
The options configured are:

- set google to default search provider and search suggestion provider
- disable Bing search
- Block intrusive ads
- Enable 'Do Not Track' request
- Enable Microsoft Defender SmartScreen checking
- Block Potentially Unwanted Applications
- Set home page to New Tab page
- Set New Tab page content to Office365 instead of news feed
- Show Home button
- Disable Edge shopping assistant
- Clear Cached images and files (but not cookies) on exit

### Copy the following, then paste into notepad and save as a .reg file, then you can import it on workstation:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"AddressBarMicrosoftSearchInBingProviderEnabled"=dword:00000000
"AdsSettingForIntrusiveAdsSites"=dword:00000002
"ClearCachedImagesAndFilesOnExit"=dword:00000001
"ConfigureDoNotTrack"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSearchProviderEnabled"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL"="url: {google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}"
"DefaultSearchProviderName"="Google"
"DefaultSearchProviderSuggestURL"="{google:baseURL}complete/search?output=chrome&q={searchTerms}"
"SmartScreenEnabled"=dword:00000001
"SmartScreenPuaEnabled"=dword:00000001
"HomepageIsNewTabPage"=dword:00000001
"NewTabPageSetFeedType"=dword:00000001
"RestoreOnStartup"=dword:00000005
"ShowHomeButton"=dword:00000001
"EdgeShoppingAssistantEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Modify SearchProvider and SearchURL using Powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the suggestions below.

1. **Problem With Default Search Provider**

I got the similar test result like yours. I will try to make some more tests and let you know about the results.

2. **How to Disable First Run Page?**

   - Open '**Local Group Policy Editor**'.
   - Navigate to the location below.

[image]

- Users can find the policy called **Hide the First-run experience and splash screen**.
- Users need to double click on it and a dialog will popup.
- Users need to click on the **enabled** option.

[image]

3. **How to Disable the scrollable Tab page?**

I try to search but did not get a group policy for it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know a user can manually remove the scrollable news section by clicking the settings icon >selecting Content off.   Hopefully there will be a way for group policy to set/mandate this for all users.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback regarding this feature. I will try to submit a feature request to Microsoft

Comment: **I don't think this works** as of Feb 2024. The group policy mentioned does not appear on my Pro installs, and the similar **Prevent the First Run webpage from opening on Microsoft Edge** does not block the first run experience.