# Microsoft Edge Chromium - GPO for setting default search engine but don't lock the setting

Tags: search, microsoft-edge, chromium, gpo

I have found no way to set the default search engine for the new Microsoft Edge without locking the settings. I've tried the well known Edge search engine GPO settings mentioned in this thread: [Edge-Chromium GP - How to set google as default, bypass first run dialog, and have tab page without news?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892120/edge-chromium-gp-how-to-set-google-as-default-bypass-first-run-dialog-and-ha). But after applying the GPO the settings are locked and users can't change it anymore.
I also did some research in the Chromium preferences documentation (https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup) with the goal to create a master preferences file, but found no parameter which will preselect another of the available search engine-presets.

Edge Version 81.0.416.68

Answer (score 0):

If you see the information while setting the **Enable the default search provider** group policy.

It is mentioned that,

> You can specify the default search provider to use by enabling the
>   rest of the default search policies. If these are left empty (not
>   configured), the user can choose the default provider.
>
> If you enable or disable this policy, users can't change or override
>   it.
>
> If you don't configure this policy, the default search provider is
>   enabled, and the user can choose the default search provider and set
>   the search provider list.

[image]

So if you enabled this group policy then the user cannot change or override it.